# Programmatically getting a list of variables

Tags: reflection, vim

Is it possible to get a list of declared variables with a VimL (aka VimScript) expression?  I'd like to get the same set of values that will be presented for a command using `-complete=expression`.  The goal is to augment that list for use in a user-defined command completion function.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `g:` as a dictionary that holds all global variables, so:

```
let globals = keys(g:)
```

will give you all the names. The same applies to the other scopes: `b:`, `s:`, `w:`, etc. See `:help internal-variables` for the complete list.

Answer (score 3):

You can get something similar using keys of `g:`, `b:`, `t:`, `w:` and `v:` dictionaries, but beware of the following facts:

1. There is no equivalent to this dictionaries if you want to complete options.
2. Some variables like `count` (but not `g:count` or `l:count`), `b:changedtick` and, maybe, others are not present in this dictionaries.
3. Some vim hacker may add key `@@@` to dictionary `g:`, but it won't make expression `g:@@@` valid variable name (but adding `000` there will). Though `g:["@@@"]` will be a valid expression.

Comment: I guess parsing the text produced by `:options` or some such could be a way to get a list of options.

Comment: @intuited `:set all` suits this need better, though I don't like using any redirections: `:redir` command will overwrite existing redirection if there is some.

Comment: Yeah, `:redir` is kind of gross, but seems to be necessary for some applications.  Thanks again for the tip on `:set all`.  BTW `count` seems to be in the `v:` dictionary: `:help v:count` mentions that `count` is an alias retained for backwards compatibility.

Comment: @intuited Yes, I meant that alias. If you want to complete, for example, `co`, you won't be shown `count` unless you write a hack that will add `count` to the list of possible variants alongside with `keys(g:)`, but won't do it if you want to complete `g:co`.

Comment: Okay, got it.  Though I notice that vim's built-in completion doesn't complete `count` either, so maybe it doesn't matter.  E.G. `:echo cou<Tab>` just gives `count(`.